# How to add a interceptor using librdkafka C++ client?

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am trying to write a Kafka producer using librdkafka C++ client, I found there is no API to add a custom interceptor in C++ version, while i found some function to add interceptor in C  which are not exposed in C++ client like

```c
rd_kafka_resp_err_t
rd_kafka_interceptor_add_on_send (
        rd_kafka_t *rk, const char *ic_name,
        rd_kafka_interceptor_f_on_send_t *on_send,
        void *ic_opaque)
```

Answer (score 1):

The interceptor interface is only available in C, not C++, but you can (carefully) use the underlying C interface with your C++ client by retrieving the C handles with the `c_*ptr()` methods.
E.g., `conf->c_global_ptr()` returns the C++ Conf object's underlying C `rd_kafka_conf_t` object.